# How to Count Vowels in a sentence in Text File (C#)

Tags: c#, counting

I have to create a small program where I have to prompt the user for idioms and store these into a text file. After that, I have to open up the text file and count the number of individual vowels in each idiom (a, e, i, o, u) and display these to the user.

Here is the code I have created so far:

```
        int numberOfIdioms;
        string fileName = "idioms.txt";
        int countA = 0, countE = 0, countI = 0, countO = 0, countU = 0;

        Console.Title = "String Functions";

        Console.Write("Please enter number of idioms: ");
        numberOfIdioms = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        string[] idioms = new string[numberOfIdioms];
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int aa = 0; aa < idioms.Length; aa++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter idiom {0}: ", aa + 1);
            idioms[aa] = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        StreamWriter myIdiomsFile = new StreamWriter(fileName);

        for (int a = 0; a < numberOfIdioms; a++)
        {
            myIdiomsFile.WriteLine("{0}", idioms[a]);
        }

        myIdiomsFile.Close();
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: 1. Prompt the user for the number of idioms and write them to a file called "idioms.txt"

2. Read the lines from idioms.txt file and display the number of vowels in each idiom

Comment: "the assignment" and "the question" aren't the same thing.

Comment: Google about FileIO as this is a very basic thing and you should learn it as part of your course. In regards to the count, just parse each character in the string (retrieved from txt file) using a switch statement against the vowels. If this makes no sense, Google will help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code to get the vowel count for a string:

```
int vowelCount = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input, "[aeoiu]").Count;
```

Replace `input` with your string variable.

If you want to count regardless of case (upper/lower), you can use:

```
int vowelCount = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(input.ToLower(), "[aeoiu]").Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

string Target = "my name and your name unknown MY NAME AND YOUR NAME UNKNOWN";

List pattern = new List { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U' };

int t = Target.Count(x => pattern.Contains(x));

Answer (score 0):

We can use regular expression to match vowels in each idoms. 
you can call the function mentioned below to get the vowel count.

> working code snippet:

```
  //below function will return the count of vowels in each idoms(input)
 public static int GetVowelCount(string idoms)
   {
       string pattern = @"[aeiouAEIOU]+"; //regular expression to match vowels
       Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);   
       return rgx.Matches(idoms).Count;
   }
```